# Export high-quality contourf plot for publication, too large

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I didn't found a topic about exporting high quality plots, generated with the contourf command using matplotlib library.

The issue I am facing is that when I export the plot as .eps with

```
fig.savefig('largecontourfplot.eps')
```

I cannot open it with inkscape to modify. It is about `100 MB` large.

Has anyone a solution for this problem? I want to avoid using .png format since I want to have vector graphics .eps or .svg. Maybe someone has a workaround.

Thank you,
Arch

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the size of your figure, or dpi?

Comment: If your contour plot has so much variability in the data that it generated hundreds of contours then it is often better to just use `pcolormesh`.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index.html#plots-of-arrays-and-fields. You can rasterize pcolormesh, while keeping the rest of the plot in vector format.